# Update row value with column name if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to do the following to a pandas dataframe:

Input data:

```
Char   A    B
Nan    0    1
Nan    1    0
```

Output:

```
Char   
B
A
```

As you can see I want to fill the value in 'Char' with a column name if the value of said column is 1.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df['Char'] = df[['A','B']].idxmax(axis=1)
df
```

Out:

```
  Char  A  B
0    B  0  1
1    A  1  0
```